# Regression model without predictors using plm in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, panel, plm

I have an unbalance panel data table with variables `ID`, `year`, and `outcome`. The data for each `ID` spans from 2005-2020, although each `ID` won't have all 15 years of data. Here's a sample:

```
ID, year, outcome
1, 2005, 70
1, 2006, 73
1, 2007, 70
1, 2008, 68
2, 2005, 65
2, 2006, 71
2, 2007, 68
2, 2008, 64
2, 2009, 63
3, 2011, 78
3, 2012, 81
4, 2008, 75
```

I want to run a `plm` regression model **without predictors** (i.e. a regression model on the intercept).

I tried running the following but get the error message "empty model":

```
feModel <- plm(damMean ~ 1, data = finalDT, model = "within", index = c("sireID", "year"))

# Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor,  : 
  empty model
```

Is this possible to do using the `plm` package in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not so much a programming question but rather a statistical question. Also I think it is not so much a question about the capabilities of package "plm" per se but rather if such a **within** model makes sense and the technical estimation approach to within models implemented.

plm's within models (fixed effect models) do not contain an intercept. Some other statistical software packages have a somewhat artifical intercept in their within models (most notably probably Stata, but gretl as well). You may want to look at `?plm::within_intercept` and the literature it references for more details about the intercept in within models.

Let's see what happens in case of only an intercept as regressor in a within model:

```
library("plm")
data("Grunfeld", package = "plm")
pGrun <- pdata.frame(Grunfeld)
plm(inv ~ 1, data = pGrun, model = "within") # errors with "empty model"

pGrun$int <- 1 # intercept
within_int <- Within(pGrun$int) # within transformation of intercept
# -> all zeros:
head(within_int)
##  1-1935 1-1936 1-1937 1-1938 1-1939 1-1940 
##       0      0      0      0      0      0 
all.equal(as.numeric(within_int), rep(0, 200L), check.attributes = FALSE)
##  TRUE
```

The within transformation of the intercept is all zeros, thus the error message by plm about an empty model is sane. gretl, an econometrics package with an intercept for within models, outputs an estimate for such an intercept-only model:

```
             coefficient   std. error   t-ratio    p-value 
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  const        145.958      7.68517      18.99    8.85e-046 ***
```

What is this value? Well it is the mean of the dependend variable

```
mean(pGrun$inv)
##   145.9582
```

Or, if you want to derive this mean by a model estimation with `plm` you can estimate a `"pooling"` model with intercept only:

```
plm(inv ~ 1, data = pGrun, model = "pooling")
##  Model Formula: inv ~ 1

##  Coefficients:
##  (Intercept) 
##       145.96
```

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed answer! I have a more general question about regression models without predictors: how would we interpret the value of the coefficient of the intercept?

Comment: I think that is included in my answer already: It is the mean value of the dependend variable. Again, this is not a programming question.

Comment: I have another non-programming question regarding this topic, so I made a post here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/535025/panel-regression-without-predictors-in-r
I hope you can help me out there